# How to convert function to MooTools?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, mootools

We have this code that auto submits our form, when users search but we do not want to use it anymore as its dirty, how can we accomplish this in MooTools?

Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autosubmit() {
    setTimeout("document.search_form.submit()", 1000);
}
</script>

<input type='text' class='home_signin_field' id='search' name='user' size='30' onchange="autosubmit()">
```

We have a autosuggest script that drops down with a list of results when typing in that field, when a result is clicked, it auto inserts text into field, that is the reason for our messy method. The autocomplete script doesn't automatically submit form.

This is our AutoSuggest script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
      var options = {
        script:"results.php?task=suggest_user&limit=3&",
      varname:"input",
      json:true,
      shownoresults:false,
      maxresults:5,
      multisuggest:false,
      callback: function (obj) {
      }
    };
    var as_json = new bsn.AutoSuggest('search', options);
  }
);
  //-->
</script>
```

I can simply add `onchange="$('search_form').submit(); return false;"` to input field, but redirects so quick the full text in field doesn't preserve, so 2 characters are caught after submission (breaking results).

Comment: Can't you simply remote the `onchange="autosubmit()"` in your input to prevent submission? It's not clear how the autosuggest and submission are actually related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<input>` is inside a `<form>` in the html you could use this:

```
document.id('search').addEvent('change',function(){   
    this.form.submit();
});
```

If not, you can call the form directly and use `.submit()`.

If it still doesn't work it might be because your "autosuggest script" does not fire a `change` event in the input field `#search`. In that case you could add this in your autosuggest script after the value of the `#search` input has been set: `document.id('search').fireEvent('change');`.

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgb4e/) if it helps.

Comment: Excellent demo and well put, however I am still having issues with the example working on our site. I have updated the first post. How to add your provided solution to the updated code I posted?

Comment: @CodyTapping, which AutoSuggest do you use? I can check it and try to figure out how it works.